# How can I add a <div> inside SVG <text>?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to add a  inside SVG text thus:

```
<text id="m1Caption" x="65px" y="40px">mass m1=<div id="m1" class="CTATTextArea"></div>kg</text>
```

I intend to create the div within the text so that the div appears inline. However, the div shows up elsewhere. I have tried position: inline in the css but it doesn't work. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please red about [<tspan>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan)

Answer (score 0):

You can't append HTML to SVG (technically you can with foreignObject, but it's a rabbit hole). Furthermore, visible elements in SVG can't be nested, so elements such as circle, rect, path and such can't have children elements.

Answer (score -2):

You can't add a div tag inside SVG.
But if you want to add a text inside SVG you can try making that SVG in FIGMA.

While exporting export as SVG and include id attributes to perform animations if you want.

https://www.figma.com/